# SQL Server 2008 Express failed to attach mdf file

Tags: sql-server

Here is the message. What's wrong with it? Is it a installtion problem?

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Cannot show requested dialog.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Parameter name: nColIndex
Actual value was -1. (Microsoft.SqlServer.GridControl)

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attaching a database in SSMS gives error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/42562/5203)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to attach the mdf using SQL Authentication, or Windows Authentication?  If using SQL Auth, you might try Windows Auth instead.

You might also want to check out this [MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/ad2b2e0d-aecb-4f95-89a8-04dd27ac4944), or [this post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/sqlexpress/thread/ed3a1c6a-2456-4930-a98d-ac75ca780f67) which suggests using the single file version of database attach:

```
USE master;
GO
EXEC sp_attach_single_file_db @dbname = 'AdventureWorks',  @physname = N'f:\dataAdventureWorks_Data.mdf';
```

**Edit:**  When running this script, you gotta be logged in as a user with at least dbcreator rights.  You may also try CREATE DATABASE FOR ATTACH as shown at [this blog post](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/24/sql-server-2005-t-sql-script-to-attach-and-detach-database/)

Comment: I'm using Windows Authentication. Yeah, I saw the post before. And that doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: The script above give me a error message:
CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Windows authentication, and had the same error with SQL Server Standard Edition because my Windows authentication login didn't have enough privileges ( was only 'public' role ) .  So logging as "sa" and  adding "sysadmin" role for my Windows account login solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks, MicMit, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue.
it appears that the error raised because i've connect to SQL SERVER 2012 INSTANCE
with Sql Server 2008 R2 management studio.
hope it help someone else too