# Cannot Attach Databases or Create new one - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server 2008 Express failed to attach mdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424811/sql-server-2008-express-failed-to-attach-mdf-file)

I use SQL Server 2008 r2,
I am new at SQL Server , so I have some example files I want to attach it.

for some reason it showing the following messegebox :

> Cannot show requested dialog.     Additional information : parameter name : nColIndex   Actual value was -1. (Microsoft.Sqlserver.GridControl)

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424811/sql-server-2008-express-failed-to-attach-mdf-file

Answer (score 8):

That's a known bug in SSMS Express.  Use T-SQL instead, and you should be successful:

```
EXEC sp_attach_db 
    @dbname = N'yourDbName',
    @filename1 = N'C:\yourMDFlocation\DB_File.mdf', 
    @filename2 = N'C:\yourLDFlocation\DB_Log.LDF'
```

Comment: sorry for the dumb question , but , what is T-SQL?

Comment: @user1054375 T-SQL is the proprietary extension to SQL used by SQL Server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043265/what-is-the-difference-between-sql-pl-sql-and-t-sql

Comment: @user1054375, John Allers hit the nail on the head.  T-SQL (Transact-SQL) is SQL Server's SQL.