# Unable to do Database Attchment in sql server2008 for existing Project

Tags: sql-server

when I am attching Database to my sql server2008 it gives an error and it is also not allowing to create new database when i am creating by default master will select if change then again before running create database command it again master selected

This Error is comming while attching Database:

Cannot show reuested dialog:

Parameter name:nColIndex
Acutual Value was -1, (Microsoft.sqlServer.GridControl)

Comment: Please ensure user has right permission to create db.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SQL Server Express edition? If you are, have a look at this post:

[Cannot Attach Databases or Create new one - SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465138/cannot-attach-databases-or-create-new-one-sql-server-2008)

It seems to be a common bug in SQL Server Express. You should be able to attach the database by using T-SQL.